# use of splice function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, console.log, splice

splice function cant be written inside a console.log ??
I tried both here's what I tried -

```
const arr1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
console.log(arr1.splice(1,4,"HI"));
```

output for this code= [ 'a', 'HI', 'f' ]

```
const arr1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
arr1.splice(1,4,"HI");`enter code here`
console.log(arr1);
```

output for this code = [ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]`

What's the difference?

Comment: This is as documented. The returned array is what is spliced *out*, not what *remains*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log is showing what the `splice` function **returned**, which is an array of the deleted items. You seem to want to see the *new* contents of the original array, which isn't what `splice` returns, so you'll have to show it separately.

```
arr1.splice(1,4,"HI")
console.log(arr1);
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
arr1.splice(1,4,"HI");
console.log(arr1);
```

or if you really want a one-liner, you could abuse the comma operator:

```
console.log((arr1.splice(1,4,"HI"), arr1)); // But please don't do this ;-)
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
console.log((arr1.splice(1,4,"HI"), arr1)); // But please don't do this ;-)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you are logging the **return value** of `splice` (An array containing the deleted elements).

In the second example you are logging the **mutated array**.

---

```js
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
const return_value = arr1.splice(1, 4, "HI");
console.log({
  return_value,
  arr1
});
```